logical error probability independent from distance in STIM default repetition code
I am testing the STIM's default implementation of repetition code with different values for the distance and rounds. It seems to me the logical error rate is independent from the distance, which I did not expect. The following code is adapted from the introductory tutorial of STIM:
import numpy as np
import stim
import pymatching
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calculate_logical_error_probability(circuit, num_shots=10_000_000):
    # Compile the circuit for sampling
    sampler = circuit.compile_detector_sampler()
    
    # Sample the circuit
    samples, observables = sampler.sample(num_shots, separate_observables=True)

    # Create a pymatching Matching object from the circuit
    matching = pymatching.Matching.from_stim_circuit(circuit)
    
    # Decode the samples
    corrections = matching.decode_batch(samples)
    
    # Calculate the logical error rate
    logical_errors = np.any(corrections, axis=1)
    logical_error_rate = np.mean(logical_errors)
    
    return logical_error_rate



def calculate_logical_error_rates(rounds_list, distance_list, error_probability, num_shots=10_000_000):

    # Initialize an empty list to store the results
    results = []

    # Loop over the parameters and calculate the logical error probability
    for rounds in rounds_list:
        for distance in distance_list:
            circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
                "repetition_code:memory",
                rounds=rounds,
                distance=distance,
                before_round_data_depolarization=error_probability,
                before_measure_flip_probability=error_probability)
            
            logical_error_rate = calculate_logical_error_probability(circuit, num_shots)
            row = {'rounds': rounds, 'distance': distance, 'logical_error_rate': logical_error_rate}
            results.append(row)
            print(row)

    # Create a DataFrame from the results
    df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)
    return df_results


def plot_logical_error_rates(df_results):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    
    for distance in df_results['distance'].unique():
        subset = df_results[df_results['distance'] == distance]
        plt.plot(subset['rounds'], subset['logical_error_rate'], label=f'Distance {distance}')
    
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xlabel('Rounds')
    plt.ylabel('Logical Error Rate')
    plt.title('Logical Error Rate vs Rounds for Different Distances')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


# Define the parameters
rounds_list = [10, 40]
distance_list = [3, 5, 7, 9]
error_probability = 0.001

# Call the method and print the results
df_results = calculate_logical_error_rates(rounds_list, distance_list, error_probability)
plot_logical_error_rates(df_results)

The resulting plot is the following. Can you explain if that is the expected behavior and why? I suspect there might be an error in my adaptation of the tutorial, still cannot spot exactly where.


Your mistake is here:
logical_errors = np.any(corrections, axis=1)

which should instead be:
logical_errors = np.any(corrections != observables, axis=1)

or, with better naming of the variables:
logical_errors = np.any(predicted_obs_flips != actual_obs_flips, axis=1)

because the detector sampler doesn't sample the values of the observables, it samples whether those values are flipped or not. And the decoder's job is to predict whether the observables were flipped, given the detector flips.
Also you shouldn't take 10 million shots all in one call like this, as it allocates a lot of memory unnecessarily. Instead compile the sampler and decoder, then use them many times in a loop. Take 1024 shots at a time, adding up the results as you go, until you get to 10 million. Even better, take shots until you've seen 1000 errors, as this will allow high-error circuits to terminate much sooner while maintaining constant relative tolerance on the estimated logical error probability. Also also, pass bit_packed=True into the sample call to produce a more compact output for faster performance; pymatching should still understand it.

This is not what you want to do:
logical_errors = np.any(corrections, axis=1)

With this, you count a logical error every time the decoder predicted that an observable was flipped. The decoder might have been correct about this prediction. A logical error happens when the decoder does not correctly predict which observables were flipped for this sample.
Quoting the linked tutorial:
def count_logical_errors(circuit: stim.Circuit, num_shots: int) -> int:
    # Sample the circuit.
    sampler = circuit.compile_detector_sampler()
    detection_events, observable_flips = sampler.sample(num_shots, separate_observables=True)

    # Configure a decoder using the circuit.
    detector_error_model = circuit.detector_error_model(decompose_errors=True)
    matcher = pymatching.Matching.from_detector_error_model(detector_error_model)

    # Run the decoder.
    predictions = matcher.decode_batch(detection_events)

    # Count the mistakes.
    num_errors = 0
    for shot in range(num_shots):
        actual_for_shot = observable_flips[shot]
        predicted_for_shot = predictions[shot]
        if not np.array_equal(actual_for_shot, predicted_for_shot):
            num_errors += 1
    return num_errors

In the for loop, for each shot, the prediction from the decoder is compared to the sampled observable_flips, which are the sampled need for logical state corrections. A logical error is counted when these two disagree, not when prediction is non-zero.
